# Resource not available in specific region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a schedule that create a 5TB disk everyday but this time it throws an error like below:

```
The zone 'projects/abcd/zones/asia-southeast2-a' does not have enough
resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or 
try again later.
```

As far as I know, I still have enough quota to create this.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: The error message is not related to your quota. Google does not have resources in that zone at that point in time for you to consume.

Comment: so there's no other way than to wait for the resource to be available in that zone?

Comment: Some suggestions that come from experience with GCP and are not facts. 1) Make sure that your credit card has sufficient credit available for the total monthly bill. 2) If you are spending large amounts, I would contact Google Cloud Billing and let them know. They might have restrictions on how much you can spend. 3) Is your account brand new? If so, you might have to wait for credit history to build. Item #2 might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can [change the destination of your snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#selecting_a_storage_location) but this may involve some additional costs (for storing depending on the location) and network charges;**

> When you create a snapshot, you can specify a storage location. The
> location of a snapshot affects its availability and can incur
> networking costs when creating the snapshot or restoring it to a new
> disk.

In some cases you may be limited to some locations if Organisation Policy requires that.

You may also [move your vm to a different zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) but it's not as easy as changing snapshots' zone.

Other than that you can't do much really. If you can't do any of the above then waiting for available resources is your only solution.

Here are some pointers on [how to build a scalable solutions in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps)  and [how to distribute your VM's across multiple zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems#distribute) to avoid possible outages. This documentation provides [information about available CPU/GPU architectures in various zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available) which may also be helpful to you.

Comment: thanks for the Answer! i was about to make this into production but even when i change zone, there's still a possibility of it getting not enough resources. so i need to rethink on this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some tips on how to design more scalable solution :)

Comment: thanks Wojtek, appreciate it, i definitely need to look this further